# How can I access second microphone signal in android device?

Tags: android, microphone, galaxy, recording

How can I access second microphone signal in android device?

I'm trying to make 2-channel noise reduction app and I don't know how to access second microphone signal.

I use Galaxy S2 which has 2 microphone(bottom and top) and when I use AudioRecord method
bottom microphone signal is the only one that can I access.

I will appreciate any response~

thanks, youna

Comment: From what I know the SDK only gives you access to the post-noise-reduction data via AudioRecord. You might need to dig into the native methods to have access to the raw data and it might be device dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the Galaxy S2, but on the devices I've worked with one could typically get the secondary mic by doing a mono recording from the CAMCORDER AudioSource. And a stereo recording would use both mics.
Most of those devices had a bottom/back mic placement rather than bottom/top, though.

Also, as Edison commented, the data that you get when you record will typically already have gone though a noise suppressor regardless of the AudioSource you use. I've never come across an Android device where you can get a raw, unfiltered stereo signal from the two built-in mics (that's not to say that no such devices exist).

Comment: It depends on your device. My answer was based on the devices I've worked with myself that have had two microphones.